# Cannot access function parameters from async function

Tags: flutter, dart

In the moment of registering, when I try to print the username which is a parameter of the function, it just won't print anything on the screen and I cannot understand why.

```
 Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String username, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      // create a new document for the user with the uid
      print(username);
      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(username);
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    } 
  }
```

Edit: this is the function which calls the registerWithEmailAndPassword function:

```
onPressed: () async {
                        if (error.length > 0)
                          error = "";
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                          setState(() => loading = true);
                          dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(username, email, password);
                          if (result == null){
                            if (this.mounted){
                            setState(() {
                              error = 'Please supply a valid email';
                              loading = false;

                            });}
                          }

                        }
                      }
```

Comment: can you provide more details?for example are you sure the passed name is not empty?or maybe the code where you are calling it from

Comment: ok are you sure the passed username is not null?there seem to be nothing wrong in the code, and is the terminal printing other things normally?

Comment: I just now realised that I was attributing the text from the username field to the email because I forgot to replace it when I copy-pasted it, it works now